# Cutoff and regularization

Tags: quantum-field-theory, regularization, renormalization

Some variant of this question has probably been asked before on this site but my idea is to work with an explicit example.

Suppose we discretize the momentum space, so we work with:
$$\Lambda^{*} := \frac{2\pi}{L}\mathbb{Z}^{d}$$
for some $L \gg 1$. The position space becomes the cartesian product of half-open intervals:
$$\Lambda = \bigg{(}\frac{-L}{2},\frac{L}{2}\bigg{]}^{d}.$$
For the free propagator, we have:
$$C(x,y) = L^{-d}\sum_{p\in \Lambda^{*}}\frac{1}{p^{2}+m^{2}}e^{ip\cdot(x-y)},$$
which still has to be regularized. We then introduce a regulator $\chi$ which is a smooth function from $\mathbb{R}^{+}$ to $[0,1]$, satisfies $\chi'(x) < 0$ for whenever $0 < x < 4$ and:
$$\chi(x) = \begin{cases}
\displaystyle 0 \quad \mbox{if $x \ge 4$} \\
\displaystyle 1 \quad \mbox{if $x\le 1$}
\end{cases}
$$
For some $\Lambda > 0$, we define:
$$\hat{C}_{\Lambda}(p) := \hat{C}(p)\chi\big{(}\frac{p^{2}}{\Lambda^{2}}\big{)}.$$

If $|p| \ge 2\Lambda$ then $\hat{C}_{\Lambda}(p) = 0$ because $\chi$ goes to zero in this case. Hence, $\hat{C}_{\Lambda}(p)$ is only nonzero if $|p|< 2\Lambda$ and because $p \in \Lambda^{*}$ originally, then we are actually reducing our $\Lambda^{*}$ to a finite lattice:
$$\Lambda^{*} \cap \{p : \hspace{0.1cm} |p|\le 2\Lambda\}.$$

However, I can still consider $C(x,y)$ and take $x=y$.

**Question:** Shouldn't the inclusion of the cutoff be equivalent to introducing a spacing (discretization) regularization on the position space $\Lambda$? But I still can take $x=y$, so nothing seems to have changed in the position space. Where is the inconsistency?

**Motivation:** The motivation for the question is that, when dealing with fermionic field theory, one usually uses Berezin integration which is algebraically defined for finitely many Grassmann generators. One typical example is:
$$\Omega_{V}(\psi) = -\log \int d\mu_{C}(\varphi)e^{-\lambda V(\psi+\varphi)}.$$
In momentum space (with cutoff) $d\mu_{C}$ would make sense if $C = \hat{C}_{\Lambda}$ but not in position space if the introduction of the cutoff function doesn't discretize $\Lambda$. I wonder if the only way of making sense of these integrals, therefore, is by discretizing + introducing a cutoff.